# Ruby and Javascript: passing a Ruby array as a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ruby

I'm trying to dynamically draw a Google Map and place a marker on it.  In my controller, I assemble an array containing the name of the businesss, latitude, longitude and a z-index.

I have an array in Ruby that is available to my Rails view:

```
@locations = [["Location One",36.0552,-114.928,1]]
```

When I try to use that array in some Javascript:

```
var loc = <%= @locations %>
```

I see this in view source:

```
var loc = [[&quot;Location One&quot;,36.0552,-114.928,1]]
```

In order for the map to display the variable needs to read like:

```
var loc = [['Location One',36.0552,-114.928,1]]
```

With the quotes intact around the first element of the array.  If I hard code that last line into the Javascript the map renders correctly.  It really seems to be the quot; tags that are messing things up.

There will be more than one location on the map so I thought an array of arrays would be the best way to get the needed data into my view.

How can I accomplish this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Corrected following DNNX's comment.

I think you need to convert it to json (a subset of JavaScript) before rendering:

```
require "json"
...
var loc = <%= @locations.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Comment: `<%= @locations.to_json %>` doesn't work. `<%= @locations.to_json.html_safe %>` does.

Comment: I didn't know about html_safe.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use html_safe to prevent the escape the quote

Comment: Providing a simple example would be useful.